# Flutter cant't align image to vertical center in ListTile with Stack

Tags: flutter, dart

What every I try column, row, center, positioned, and aligned widgets, I still can't seem to align the dog image to the vertical center.

[image]

Does anyone know how to do this

Here is my widget

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
final dogTypes = dog.type!.map((type) => type.name).toList();
final teams = dog.teams.map((team) => team.name).toList();
return GestureDetector(
  onTap: () => viewDogProfile(dog, index),
  child: SizedBox(
    width: double.infinity,
    child: Card(
      shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(14),
      ),
      margin: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 25),
      child: Padding(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 8),
        child: ListTile(
          leading: Container(
            width: 65,
            height: 65,
            decoration: const BoxDecoration(
              shape: BoxShape.circle,
            ),
            child: Stack(
              children: [
                CachedNetworkImage(
                  imageUrl: dog.image.url,
                  imageBuilder: (context, imageProvider) => Container(
                    height: 65,
                    width: 65,
                    decoration: BoxDecoration(
                      shape: BoxShape.circle,
                      image: DecorationImage(
                        image: imageProvider,
                        fit: BoxFit.cover,
                      ),
                      border: Border.all(
                        color: accentColor,
                        width: 2,
                      ),
                      boxShadow: [
                        BoxShadow(
                          color: Colors.black87.withOpacity(0.6),
                          spreadRadius: 0.8,
                          blurRadius: 2,
                          offset: const Offset(1, 1),
                        ),
                      ],
                    ),
                  ),
                  placeholder: (context, url) =>
                      const CircularProgressIndicator(
                    color: primaryColor,
                  ),
                  errorWidget: (context, url, error) =>
                      const Icon(Icons.error),
                ),
                DogStatusIcon(
                  dogStatus: dog.status,
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
          title: Row(
            children: [
              Flexible(
                child: Padding(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 8),
                  child: Text(
                    dog.name,
                    style: AppStyles.dogProfileCardHeaderTextStyle,
                    maxLines: 1,
                    softWrap: true,
                    overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
          subtitle: Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 5),
            child: Column(
              children: [
                Row(
                  crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                  children: [
                    const Text(
                      'Teams: ',
                      style: AppStyles.dogProfileCardSubHeaderTextStyle,
                    ),
                    Flexible(
                      child: Text(
                        teams
                            .toString()
                            .replaceAll('[', '')
                            .replaceAll(']', ''),
                        style:
                            AppStyles.dogProfileCardSubHeaderDataTextStyle,
                        maxLines: 1,
                        softWrap: false,
                        overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
                      ),
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
                Row(
                  crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                  children: [
                    const Text(
                      'Breed: ',
                      style: AppStyles.dogProfileCardSubHeaderTextStyle,
                    ),
                    Flexible(
                      child: Text(
                        dog.breed.name,
                        style:
                            AppStyles.dogProfileCardSubHeaderDataTextStyle,
                        maxLines: 1,
                        softWrap: true,
                        overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
                      ),
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
                Row(
                  crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                  children: [
                    const Text(
                      'Type: ',
                      style: AppStyles.dogProfileCardSubHeaderTextStyle,
                    ),
                    Flexible(
                      child: Text(
                        dogTypes
                            .toString()
                            .replaceAll('[', '')
                            .replaceAll(']', ''),
                        style:
                            AppStyles.dogProfileCardSubHeaderDataTextStyle,
                        maxLines: 1,
                        softWrap: false,
                        overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
                      ),
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
          trailing: Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 10),
            child: IconButton(
              icon: const Icon(
                Icons.keyboard_arrow_right_rounded,
                color: accentColor,
                size: 28,
              ),
              onPressed: () {
                viewDogProfile(dog, index);
              },
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    ),
  ),
);
```

}

Comment: have you removed the container or at least its height when trying `Center`? I would assume that Center should be the Widget to go for and try otherwise what blocks it from working properly

Comment: No I can;t add center there is some issue with the stack